# I want to access a particular element within a std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, openssl, unique-ptr

Currently I have:

```
using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)>;
```

This is initialized with the code:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);
```

Now I want to access the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` within this pointer for a function in the format:

```
int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x, int padding);
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Try `ctx.get()` (see [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has a member function [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) which returns a pointer to the managed object or `nullptr` if no object is owned.

In your case, the managed object is of type `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` and the `unique_ptr` is `ctx`.

So `ctx.get()` will give you a pointer to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`.